# Properties of complexification of real schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes

We define the complexification $X_\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ of a real scheme $X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}$ to be the fiber product $X_\mathbb{C} = X \times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}} \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$.

In general, does complexification of real schemes preserve dimension? Smoothness? Would anyone know a reference that discusses properties of this complexification in detail?

Comment: That this preserves smoothness is follows from the facts that smooth maps are preserved by base change and automorphisms are smooth (they are etale and hence smooth of dimension zero).

Comment: Please use `\operatorname{Spec}` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ - this produces better spacing.

Comment: See 11.2.J, 11.2.16 , 12.2.G and 21.3.C In Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry